# Xubuntu 18.04 - Slow boot time - tlp.service 2min 43s

Tags: boot, xubuntu, tlp

I'm using an old laptop, with xubuntu 18.04. 4GB RAM + i3-2350M cpu.

I've just upgraded and found the boot time is extremely slow. I've searched and tried various things, but I can't find what is causing tlp.service to run so slow. Previously the boot was not as long, and once it has booted up it runs just fine.

Any ideas or tips please? Thank you in advance.

Firstly, systemd-analyze time outputs:

```
Startup finished in 7.799s (kernel) + 3min 17.996s (userspace) = 3min 
25.796s
graphical.target reached after 34.975s in userspace
```

systemd-analyze blame outputs

```
2min 43.014s tlp.service
25.077s dev-sda1.device
19.910s systemd-journal-flush.service
16.803s systemd-sysctl.service
12.907s snap-gnome\x2dcalculator-238.mount
7.741s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
5.657s systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service
5.372s snapd.service
3.730s udisks2.service
3.271s networkd-dispatcher.service
2.389s systemd-modules-load.service
2.159s NetworkManager.service
2.045s accounts-daemon.service
2.042s ModemManager.service
2.011s keyboard-setup.service
1.893s grub-common.service
1.554s preload.service
1.475s avahi-daemon.service
1.301s wpa_supplicant.service
1.295s lightdm.service
1.275s systemd-random-seed.service
1.159s swapfile.swap
918ms polkit.service
```

Comment: Same here. Takes about three minutes to boot up since upgrade to 18.04. My laptop has  i5 with 8GB of ram. Any help to speed up would be very welcome.